Google Drive golang api unable to see any file
I am trying to connect to my google drive via api using Service Account, but when i try to query the list, it returns empty result.
Below is my code:
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := drive.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("ServiceAccountCred.json"), option.WithScopes(drive.DriveScope))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Warning: Unable to create drive Client %v", err)
    }
    r, err := srv.Files.List().PageSize(10).
        Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve files: %v", err)
    }
    for _, res := range r.Files {
        fmt.Println(res.Name)
    }
}


My ServiceAccountCred was generated directly via the Service Accounts page on Google Cloud (Add Key > download), and there are no errors while creating the DriveService. What am i doing wrong?

A service account is not you it has its own Google drive account.
When it is created it has no files in it
Good news your code works perfectly 
